# Stability of discrete-time dynamical systems using Lyapunov stability

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions, discrete-time

I am studying the use of LMIs as an analysis tool for discrete-time dynamical systems. Consider the autonomous discrete-time system given by
$$
x_{_{k+1}} = A x_{_k} \tag{1} \label{sys}
$$

where $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $

In the textbook *LMIs in Control Systems: Analysis, Design and Applications* by Duan and Yu, the following condition is given for the stability of $\eqref{sys}$ using Lyapunov stability
$$
APA^{\text{T}} - P < 0  \tag{2} \label{lyap1}
$$

for some $ P = P^{\text{T}} < 0 $. In other words, if some permissible $P$ exists such that $\eqref{lyap1}$ is satisfied, then the system in $\eqref{sys}$ is stable.

I am having difficulty understanding where $\eqref{lyap1}$ comes from and here is why. First, we define the following Lyapunov function
$$
V_{_k} = x_{_k} P x_{_k} < 0  
$$

Then, by Lyapunov stability theorem we need the following
$$
V_{_{k+1}} - V_{_{k}} < 0
\\  
\implies x_{_{k+1}}^{\text{T}} P x_{_{k+1}} - x_{_{k}}^{\text{T}} P x_{_{k}} < 0
$$

Substituting $\eqref{sys}$ into the above inequality yields the following

$$
x_{_{k+1}}^{\text{T}} \left( A^{\text{T}} P A - P \right) x_{_{k}} < 0
$$

Which implies
$$
A^{\text{T}} P A - P < 0 \tag{3} \label{lyap2}
$$

The book refrenced previously uses $\eqref{lyap1}$ throughout the text. However, I have seen $\eqref{lyap2}$ in several other textbooks and I fully understand how it is derived. I suspect that $\eqref{lyap1}$ and $\eqref{lyap2}$ are equivalent; however I do not know how to show this.

My best guess is to note that if the matrix $ A $ is stable (i.e., eigenvalues reside within the unit circle), then so must the eigenvalues of $ A^{\text{T}} $ (since the eigenvalues of $A$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $A^{\text{T}}$). If we substitute $ A^{\text{T}} $ for $ A $ in $\eqref{lyap2}$ then we get $\eqref{lyap1}$; however, this reasoning seems weak. Is there a better way to show that $\eqref{lyap1}$ is equivalent to $\eqref{lyap2}$

Comment: Your reasoning is fine. Otherwise you can pre and posy multiply the LMI by $Q=P^{-1}$. Then try to manipulate it with Schur complements.

Comment: Thanks KBS. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but be aware that there is a potential pitfall:

If $A$ is Schur (all eigenvalues of $A$ are inside the open unit circle), then there exists $P>0$ and $Q>0$ such that

$$
A^TPA-P=-Q<0 \tag{1}
$$

As you correctly stated, if $A$ is Schur, so is $A^T$, so there exist $\hat{P}>0$ and $\hat{Q}>0$ such that

$$
A\hat{P}A^T-\hat{P}=-\hat{Q}<0 \tag{2}
$$

Note that by this argument, $(1)$ implies $(2)$, as you suspected, since both $-Q$ and $-\hat{Q}$ are negative definite. However, the equalities lead to different matrices in general. I.e. we have
$$
\begin{align}
P&\neq\hat{P}\\
Q&\neq\hat{Q}
\end{align}
$$
in general.

This pitfall is amplified by the fact that the Matlab function [`dlyap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyap.html), which is supposed to solve the discrete time Lyapunov equation, solves $(2)$ instead of $(1)$, so you have to pass $A^T$ as an argument to get the solution to $(1)$, which is usually what is desired.

Edit: Btw, why do you think that "this reasoning seems weak"? I second the comment by KBS that your reasoning looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you SampleTime.  Your answer is very helpful. I hadn't considered that $P$ was not, in general, the same for (1) and (2). Also very useful to know how dlyap works. To answer your question truthfully, my reasoning seemed weak to me because it seemed so simple and I lack confidence. Something I am hoping to improve.

Comment: @AdamsK I see. However, your reasoning was better than mine since in my answer, initially I mixed up "Schur" with "Hurwitz" (I corrected that typo in the meantime).

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to the previous good answer and an extension of my comment. We have that $A$ is Schur stable if and only if there exists a symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ such that $$A^TPA-P\prec0$$ where the inequality symbol means "negative definite".

If we apply once the Schur complement, we get that those conditions are equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-P & A^T\\A & -P^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\prec0$$

and applying it once more yields

$$P^{-1}\succ0,\ AP^{-1}A^T-P^{-1}\prec0.$$

Since $P$ is positive definite, then so is $P^{-1}$ and this proves the equivalence between the LMI conditions.

We can also state the following result:

Let $P\succ0$ be given, then the following statements are equivalent:

- $V(x)=x^TPx$ is a Lyapunov function for the system $x_{k+1}=Ax_k$
- $W(y)=y^TP^{-1}y$ is a Lyapunov function for the system $y_{k+1}=A^Ty_k$.

Note that this is only true when the system is LTI, the story is a bit different in the LTV case.